# Different objects for saving and displaying?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an invoice object that has an account object inside it. When displaying the invoice to a user, I have the following object:

```
invoice : {
   Number : 1234,
   Account : { id: 12345,
               name: "Test account"
              }
}
```

When saving an invoice, the user can select the account from a drop down. In that case, all I really need is the id of that account so my object will look something like this:

```
invoice : {
   Number : 1234,
   AccountId : 12345
}
```

My question is: Do I need to create two different objects one for saving and another one for displaying the invoice? If not, how would you handle this?

Thanks!!

Comment: "Do I need... ?" If that's the question, then the answer is: "No, you don't need to"

Comment: Hey Mati, how would you handle that?

Comment: Can the first object be used to save?  If so just re-use it.  Duplicating data across objects is problematic and prone to errors.

Comment: Hey Mark, the problem I was having with that approach is the following: When saving an account, the "name" property is required. So the [Required] attribute was added to that class in the model on the server. If I also set the name, I feel like I'm sending too much data to the server when all I need is an Id. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Create another property "AccountId" in same javascript object and delete unwanted property just before saving it.

invoice.AccountId = invoice.Account.id;
delete invoice['Account'];

Comment: Hello Suyash,your solution suggests that I still need two objects (one for saving and one for displaying), am I correct? If this doesn't make sense, take a look to the comments under my question.